# Problems using an existing Firefox Profile on Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, firefox-profile

I am having problems using an existing Firefox Profile in Jenkins server. Locally, everything is working fine.
I am using the following code block to use the Firefox profile:

```html
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe");
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile testprofile = profile.getProfile("selenium-profile");
FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
opt.setProfile(testprofile);
WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(opt);
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

The error shown on Jenkins:

```html
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unexpected value for profile: null
```

Comment: what is `getProfile()` ? and this is not how you should pass local path `C:\\path\\to\`

Comment: @cruisepandey getProfile("selenium-profile") is used to get an existing Firefox Profile through FirefoxOptions.

Comment: Which Selenium version are you on ?

Comment: I am using version 3.11.0

Comment: Everything works fine with default profile.